# C++ What to choose are default parameter for my classes constructor?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ coming from C and Java. I have a good understanding of C fundamentals but I am having trouble with C++ constructors. I have a class called `Node` which I want to have just one constructor which takes an integer. I don't want a `Node` to be created with no integer. Therefore I have:

```
class Node
{
    // Let BST directly access members.
    friend class BST;
    public:
        // Constructor.
        Node(int i);
        int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    protected:
        int value;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
};

// Constructor
Node::Node(int i)
{
    value = i;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler can't find a default constructor since I haven't (and don't want to) set a default value for the parameter. I understand that this would work: `Node(int i = 0);` but the thing is that `i` could be any possible integer. What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks.

**Edit**

The only way I create Nodes is like this: `Node new_node(i);` where `i` is an int.

Comment: "I don't want a `Node` to be created with no integer" -- If you don't want to set a default value for that parameter, then explicitly instantiate it with an integer argument. Please include `Node` usage for more context.

Comment: The compiler is complaining about the lack of a default constructor because you are likely using this class in a place where default instances of the object can be created.  For example, if you declare a `std::vector<Node>` somewhere.  Can you share the code that is referencing Node?

Comment: Probably the only use of `Node` will be in class `BST`. Then its silly to both limit access and grant full access.

Comment: If you only create nodes like that, you don't need a default constructor, and moreover, you *should not* declare and/or define it. If the compiler complains about it, then you use your class in some different way somewhere. Can you post the exact line of code which the compiler doesn't like?